# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted while running puppeteer JavaScript node

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a script which scrapes through several URLs in an infinite loop and notifies me of any changes to the website. Every time I leave it running for a while, I come back to find that it has completed tens/hundreds of iterations of the loop, but I eventually this error.

```
[Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\puppeteer_dev_chrome_profile-3thzgE\CrashpadMetrics-active.pma'] {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'unlink',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\puppeteer_dev_chrome_profile-3thzgE\\CrashpadMetrics-active.pma'
}
```

This error does not appear to happen on a particular line, because as mentioned the script has been through several complete iterations of the loop before getting this error.

I googled this error, but it seems that people are only really experiencing it with NPM or if they do experience it with puppeteer it is on a particular line of their code. When I read the .pma file using an online .pma reader this is the message I got:

```
 CrashpadMetrics UMA.PersistentAllocator.CrashpadMetrics.UsedPct UMA.PersistentAllocator.CrashpadMetrics.Errors Crashpad.HandlerLifetimeMilestone Stability.BrowserExitCodes
```

Comment: Was the answer provided by @Andris good for you? Please accept if so? I've the same issue. Lots of successes and then a stack of these popup. I cannot do the exclusion list adjustment at my work per IT. I don't believe that is actually the answer though. In our cases it works for thousands and then we're seeing these CrashpadMetrics unlink errors.

Comment: @NeilGuyLindberg I did not attempt to fix the issue using Andris' answer, so I cannot accept it yet. However, I am not entirely sure either that it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

For me worked doing this

While this is annoying behaviour, there is a workaround: close all pages before closing the browser

`let pages = await browser.pages(); await Promise.all(pages.map(page =>page.close())); await browser.close();`

https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/puppeteer/puppeteer/6563/739149056

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 3):

If you're running this on Windows to me in a similar situation the solution was to add the node process to the exclusion list of Windows Security. I think it's preventing access to some temp file and node fails on that.

Comment: do you simply type `node` to the exclusion list? Not the folder or anything right?

Comment: yes, I only added "node" as a process name to the exclusion list, but adding the temp folder could work too

Comment: Confirming that adding Temp folder to Windows Defender exclusion list did the trick.